# how do I remotely call a function of an applet that is just being debugged in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, applet, fest

When I call a certain function of my applet in the browser via javascript I get an exception. However, I don't want to debug that applet while it runs in the browser, I want to start it via Debug as... in Eclipse, and then somehow remotely call that function. Is that possible? If so, how?

Alternatively, when writing a test case using the FEST framework, can I call that function via the framework or any other means?

Comment: Your question is very broad, perhaps overly broad, and I don't think lends itself to a single simple answer based on the limited information so far provided. Having said that, I can state some general principles such as, best would be for your program to be fully modular, using good OOP principles such that each component of the program, be it the logic or sub-portions of the GUI, is in separate classes and even packages and can be tested in isolation. If you've done this, then what you request should be easy to do, but the details of *how* will depend much on the details you've yet to share.

Comment: Maybe you can answer the second question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FEST framework, sorry.

Comment: *"the browser via javascript I get an exception"* Some exceptions are caused **because** a method is called by JS.  What is the exception?

Comment: just an NPE, nothing descriptive. Never mind, I thought one can call remotely from Eclipse to the applet running in Eclipse. As it seems impossible, I must get a stack trace or even debug remotely.

Answer (score 0):

No. I thought one can call remotely from Eclipse to the applet running in Eclipse. As it seems impossible, I must get a stack trace or even debug remotely the applet running in a browser.